# Global Operations don't work on Windows 8.1

Tags: backwards-compatibility, windows-8.1, global-operations

I recently installed Global Operations on my Windows 8.1 laptop (Dell 15R N5110).

The intro video plays at the start of the game but after that I get the error "Global Operations Client has Stopped Working".

How can I fix this? I tried running the game in compatibility mode for Windows 7 but this did not work.

Comment: Try to run compatibility for windows XP instead. As this game came out 13 years ago in 2002. You may have to download tools for this to be possible, if it even is in windows 8.1.

Comment: I tried for Windows XP as well. Did not work.What tools do i need to download?

Comment: The tools I spoke of were those to actually run compatibility for XP. But since you already had the ability to try, then you have no need to download it. Tried to also run with all the other compatibility settings, such as deactivate visual themes, run in 256 colors etc?

Comment: Nope did not work either, Also i installed DirectX 9 too. That did not work too. The game worked perfectly on Windows 7 last i remember.

Answer (score 1):

1. Right Click `ArchClient.exe` and select `Properties`.
2. Then go to Compatibility tab.
3. Check `Run  program in compatibility mode for:`.
4. Select `Windows xp service pack 3`.
5. Check `Run  program as administrator`.
6. Click `Apply` and then `OK`

Game will work 100%.