# Global Operations goes to small black box after Intro Windows 10

Tags: backwards-compatibility, global-operations

After the intro animation plays, it jumps to a small black box and then shuts off[image]

Comment: Interesting.  Global Operations needs admin access to run?  Why is that?

Comment: it didn't, i ticked the box while trying different compatibility modes and forgot to take it off.

Comment: Ah, I assume you tried the solution [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/205146/global-operations-dont-work-on-windows-8-1) for that?

Comment: So i did the compatibility change for Globalops.exe but not Archclient.exe because can't find that file

Comment: Well, how did you install the game? Do you have the disk?